# R dplyr conditional sum with mutate

Tags: r, count, sum, dplyr, conditional-statements

I currently have a dataset in the below format

```
id, date,         category,      city
1, 2016-01-01,       A            CityA
2, 2016-01-01,       B            CityA
```

etc.

I'm trying to use mutate such that it can give me a conditional running count in the last 30 days or x time frame.

To start I tried using to see if it works and extend it from there

```
  mutate(df, last_thirty_day_count = sum(df$id < id & df$city == city))
```

But it just gives me zeroes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have capital letters in your dataset but lower-case letters in your code? ID vs. id, City v. city?

Comment: Sorry, that's unintentional

Comment: Maybe you can show an example of the output you would like to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a slightly longer example dataset

```
set.seed(8675309)
sampleData <-
  data_frame(id = 1:20
             , date = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01")
                          , as.Date("2017-01-20")
                          , by = "day")
             , category = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, TRUE)
             , city = sample(letters[1:3], 20, TRUE)
             )
```

Then, just decide what counts as a qualifying observation. It is unclear from your question what cut off(s) you want to use. Here, I am using January 4th as a cutoff, but you could use whatever is appropriate for your case. Then, `group_by` the variable you want to count for, and just add them up. This assumes that they are in in order, if they are not, make sure to `arrange` them first.

```
sampleData %>%
  mutate(QualifiyingObs = date > "2017-01-04") %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(CountOfQual = cumsum(QualifiyingObs))
```

Gives

```
      id       date category  city QualifiyingObs CountOfQual
   <int>     <date>    <chr> <chr>          <lgl>       <int>
1      1 2017-01-01        A     a          FALSE           0
2      2 2017-01-02        B     c          FALSE           0
3      3 2017-01-03        C     c          FALSE           0
4      4 2017-01-04        C     a          FALSE           0
5      5 2017-01-05        A     b           TRUE           1
6      6 2017-01-06        C     c           TRUE           1
7      7 2017-01-07        C     a           TRUE           1
8      8 2017-01-08        C     a           TRUE           2
9      9 2017-01-09        C     a           TRUE           3
10    10 2017-01-10        B     c           TRUE           2
11    11 2017-01-11        C     c           TRUE           3
12    12 2017-01-12        B     c           TRUE           4
13    13 2017-01-13        B     a           TRUE           4
14    14 2017-01-14        A     b           TRUE           2
15    15 2017-01-15        C     a           TRUE           5
16    16 2017-01-16        C     b           TRUE           3
17    17 2017-01-17        C     b           TRUE           4
18    18 2017-01-18        A     b           TRUE           5
19    19 2017-01-19        C     a           TRUE           6
20    20 2017-01-20        C     c           TRUE           5
```